# Peut-on mettre des césures aux prénoms ?

Tags: typographie

Dans ma composition typographique, j’ai obtenu le résultat suivant :

[image: Rejet à la ligne sans césure]

Je me demandais donc s’il était correct de mettre une césure à *Dominique*.
Et si oui, à quels endroits la césure est-elle correcte ?

J’aurais dis ici : Do-mi-ni-que

Comment: Le découpage des mots en syllables? césure, c'est pour une coupure ou pause entre les mots dans un vers...

Comment: [Césure (typographie)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sure_(typographie)#:~:text=En%20typographie%20et%20en%20orthographe,une%20langue%20%C3%A0%20l'autre.) *En typographie et en orthographe, la coupure de mot, parfois appelée aussi césure, est l'opération qui consiste à couper par un trait d'union conditionnel en fin de ligne un mot qui n'entrerait pas dans la justification. Cette coupure obéit à des règles bien précises qui varient d'une langue à l'autre.*

Comment: @Lambie comme l’explique jiliagre, en typographie la *césure* n’a rien à voir avec la *césure* en poésie.

Comment: Et pour le faire il faut: Règles linguistiques
La séquence de césure **s'effectue selon le découpage syllabique**, en essayant si possible de couper entre préfixes et radicaux. [la même page que césure (typographique) de jlliagre. Oui, en versification, c'est seulement une pause pour la lecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La première recommandation consiste à éviter si possible de séparer prénoms et noms, mais plus la place est réduite, plus on est nécessairement tolérant. Ensuite, on évite aussi de découper prénoms et noms propres (sauf composés et contenant donc déjà un trait d'union) mais ici, le respect de cette deuxième règle impose une ligne supplémentaire avec un nombre isolé, ce qui fait aussi parti de ce que l'on cherche à éviter.

Pour limiter le nombre de lignes au nécessaire, il faut donc découper l'un des prénoms. Cette découpe se fait en s'appuyant sur l'étymologie ou les syllabes graphiques, pas les syllabes phoniques. On cherche aussi à éviter les coupures malsonnantes, ce qui peut conduire à éviter "*‑nique*".

Je ne sais pas pourquoi tu as mis des points médians entre les prénoms d'Ingres mais l'usage et de simplement les juxtaposer (cf: [Frank Antoni](https://franckantoni.com/prenoms-juxtaposes/)), ce qui donnerait par exemple :

> **Jean Auguste Domi-
>
> nique INGRES<sup>1</sup>, 89**

> **Jean Auguste Do-
>
> minique INGRES, 89**

Une autre approche qui éviterait de couper tout prénom serait d'utiliser une abréviation pour Jean :

> **J. Auguste Dominique
>
> INGRES, 89**

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Absence de petites capitales pour le patronyme à cause de l'éditeur de stack-exchange.</sub>